# TensorFlow: training on my own image

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to TensorFlow. I am looking for the help on the image recognition where I can **train my own image** dataset.

Is there any example for training the new dataset?

Comment: I have read this http://googleresearch.blogspot.hk/2016/03/train-your-own-image-classifier-with.html    However, i have no idea that where should I change the code.

Comment: new link location http://ai.googleblog.com/2016/03/train-your-own-image-classifier-with.html

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you are interested in how to input your own data in TensorFlow, you can look at [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#decoding_image_data_and_resizing_it).
I've also written a guide with best practices for CS230 at Stanford [here](https://cs230-stanford.github.io/tensorflow-input-data.html#building-an-image-data-pipeline).

---

### New answer (with `tf.data`) and with labels

With the introduction of `tf.data` in `r1.4`, we can create a batch of images without placeholders and without queues. The steps are the following:

1. Create a list containing the filenames of the images and a corresponding list of labels
2. Create a `tf.data.Dataset` reading these filenames and labels
3. Preprocess the data
4. Create an iterator from the `tf.data.Dataset` which will yield the next batch

The code is:

```
# step 1
filenames = tf.constant(['im_01.jpg', 'im_02.jpg', 'im_03.jpg', 'im_04.jpg'])
labels = tf.constant([0, 1, 0, 1])

# step 2: create a dataset returning slices of `filenames`
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))

# step 3: parse every image in the dataset using `map`
def _parse_function(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32)
    return image, label

dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
dataset = dataset.batch(2)

# step 4: create iterator and final input tensor
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
images, labels = iterator.get_next()
```

Now we can run directly `sess.run([images, labels])` without feeding any data through placeholders.

---

### Old answer (with TensorFlow queues)

To sum it up you have multiple steps:

1. Create a list of filenames (ex: the paths to your images)
2. Create a TensorFlow **filename queue**
3. Read and decode each image, resize them to a fixed size (necessary for batching)
4. Output a batch of these images

---

The simplest code would be:

```
# step 1
filenames = ['im_01.jpg', 'im_02.jpg', 'im_03.jpg', 'im_04.jpg']

# step 2
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

# step 3: read, decode and resize images
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, content = reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=3)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224, 224])

# step 4: Batching
image_batch = tf.train.batch([resized_image], batch_size=8)
```

Comment: For shuffle_batch(), it requires at least 4 arguments. After I adding two more arguments: num_threads=1, capacity=5000. It says: TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.

Comment: You are right, the first argument of `tf.train.batch` or `tf.train.shuffle_batch` should be a list `[image]` instead of just `image`. I fixed it in the code.

Comment: @Olivier Moindrot Sorry, I still have some error. It says: ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(3)])]. These error happens in the batching step.

Comment: Once again you are right, I fixed it in the code. You have to resize all the images to the same shape to make a batch of them.

Comment: @Olivier Moindrot Thank you very much. It works now. I want to ask, after training the model, how can I classify the input image with my owned database?

Comment: If you have the labels of the training images, you should also get them as input and batch them with the images: `image_batch, label_batch  = tf.train.batch([resized_image, label], batch_size=8)`. Then you have to build a model with images as input and labels as output, refer to [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html) for more info.

Comment: @Olivier Moindrot What if I am doing one class classification. I only got the data for one class. I wanna classify between "Target" and "Outlier". Then how can I make up an array for label?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112762/discussion-between-olivier-moindrot-and-clwong).

Comment: `resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(images, 224, 224)` Here, the first argument of resize_images method should be image instead of images, right?

Comment: resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(images, [224, 224])

Comment: where will the image labels go into?

Comment: thank's Mr @olivier-moindrot but if I have a batch of picture format `.tif`

Comment: Thanks, Mr @olivier-moindrot  I used  `tf.image.decode_gif`  and this my   [DataSetGen](https://github.com/SakhriHoussem/RestNet/blob/master/DataSetGen.py) 
 code but I don't know If this the right way

Comment: How to handle the labels in such case?

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot i got error out of range at get_next when the files are only 2, and 2 matching label [0,1] instead of 4 files and labels [0,1,0,1]

Comment: @datdinhquoc: if you have only two files and labels, with a batch size of 2, you can only do one iteration and then you will receive an `OutOfRange` error.

Comment: After train my data ,how can use to detect a image ?

Comment: How about if there is more than three 3 channel image and format of file .mat.. the code will be same?

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA: in this case you need to change the `_parse_function` to read the .mat file

Comment: from step 1, I have 100's images and stored in a folder like Root directory -> Class1 ->  images; Class 2 -> images; Class 3 -> images;
how I will read all the images with the label as folder name?

Comment: You can just get all the filenames and labels in python, then use my code to put it in tensorflow

Comment: for Tensorflow 2, replace `tf.read_file(filename)` with `tf.io.read_file(filename)`

Comment: Hey @OlivierMoindrot , thank you for this answer. I'm encountering an issue understanding the expected input for TFLite model. Can you please take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63486440/use-tensorflow-model-with-swift-for-ios

Comment: how do you resize the images in the new version?

Comment: @SamanthaCruz: you can add it in the `_parse_function`

Answer (score 8):

Based on @olivier-moindrot's answer, but for Tensorflow 2.0+:

```
# step 1
filenames = tf.constant(['im_01.jpg', 'im_02.jpg', 'im_03.jpg', 'im_04.jpg'])
labels = tf.constant([0, 1, 0, 1])

# step 2: create a dataset returning slices of `filenames`
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))

def im_file_to_tensor(file, label):
    def _im_file_to_tensor(file, label):
        path = f"../foo/bar/{file.numpy().decode()}"
        im = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(path), channels=3)
        im = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32) / 255.0
        return im, label
    return tf.py_function(_im_file_to_tensor, 
                          inp=(file, label), 
                          Tout=(tf.float32, tf.uint8))

dataset = dataset.map(im_file_to_tensor)
```

If you are hitting an issue similar to:

> ValueError: Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank

when passing tf.data.Dataset tensors to model.fit, then take a look at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24520. A fix for the code snippet above would be:

```
def im_file_to_tensor(file, label):
    def _im_file_to_tensor(file, label):
        path = f"../foo/bar/{file.numpy().decode()}"
        im = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(path), channels=3)
        im = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32) / 255.0
        return im, label

    file, label = tf.py_function(_im_file_to_tensor, 
                                 inp=(file, label), 
                                 Tout=(tf.float32, tf.uint8))
    file.set_shape([192, 192, 3])
    label.set_shape([])
    return (file, label)
```

Answer (score 0):

**2.0 Compatible Answer using Tensorflow Hub**: **`Tensorflow Hub`** is a Provision/Product Offered by `Tensorflow`, which comprises the Models developed by Google, for Text and Image Datasets.

It **`saves Thousands of Hours of Training Time and Computational Effort`**, as it reuses the Existing Pre-Trained Model.

If we have an Image Dataset, we can take the Existing Pre-Trained Models from TF Hub and can adopt it to our Dataset.

Code for Re-Training our Image Dataset using the Pre-Trained Model, MobileNet, is shown below:

```
import itertools
import os

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

module_selection = ("mobilenet_v2_100_224", 224) #@param ["(\"mobilenet_v2_100_224\", 224)", "(\"inception_v3\", 299)"] {type:"raw", allow-input: true}
handle_base, pixels = module_selection
MODULE_HANDLE ="https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/{}/feature_vector/4".format(handle_base)
IMAGE_SIZE = (pixels, pixels)
print("Using {} with input size {}".format(MODULE_HANDLE, IMAGE_SIZE))

BATCH_SIZE = 32 #@param {type:"integer"}

#Here we need to Pass our Dataset

data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'flower_photos',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
    untar=True)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(MODULE_HANDLE, trainable=do_fine_tuning),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(train_generator.num_classes, activation='softmax',
                          kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001))
])
model.build((None,)+IMAGE_SIZE+(3,))
model.summary()
```

Complete Code for Image Retraining Tutorial can be found in this [Github Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb).

More information about Tensorflow Hub can be found in this [TF Blog](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2018/03/introducing-tensorflow-hub-library.html).

The Pre-Trained Modules related to Images can be found in this [TF Hub Link](https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=image-augmentation,image-classification,image-feature-vector,image-generator,image-object-detection,image-others,image-style-transfer,image-rnn-agent).

All the Pre-Trained Modules, related to Images, Text, Videos, etc.. can be found in this [TF HUB Modules Link](https://tfhub.dev/).

Finally, this is the [Basic Page for Tensorflow Hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub).

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset consists of subfolders, you can use `ImageDataGenerator` it has `flow_from_directory` it helps to load data from a directory,

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_path, target_size=(img_height,img_weight), batch_size=32 ,color_mode="grayscale")
```

The structure of the folder hierarchy can be as follows,

```
train 
    -- cat
    -- dog
    -- moneky
```