# How can i use my own images to train my CNN neural network in tensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently working on a program that uses a CNN tensorflow neural network and I want to use my own images to train and test it, please I want some advice because I am new in deep learning

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow: training on my own image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340129/tensorflow-training-on-my-own-image)

Answer (score 0):

Download the ronnie package from python.[{pythonpath}\scripts\pip3 ronnie]
Construct the training data structure as [label, image pixel] and execute the below code to create the training data.

dataFileLoc = os.path.join(dir,"./data/digitalRec/train.csv")
orgDF = collector.initial(dataFileLoc)

########################################################################### Return Object from buildFormDF are ImgXs and LabelYs in dict Structure

## {meta.DATA_INPUTXs: imgXs, meta.DATA_LABELYs: labelYs}

##########################################################################    trainData       = collector.buildFromDF(orgDF,batchNum=1, batchSize=30000)