# TensorFlow : create own dataset for training with different size of image

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

Hello I continue to learn about the deep learning, so i try to creat my own data set for training. 
I have data set of cat and dog(1000 images of cat & 10000 images of dogs) with DIFFERENT size (because I dont find data set with same size) so I need to resize them.
My code return no error but tensorflow doesnt fill my batch and I really dont understand why. It is my first script in deep learning so its complicated for me to find what is it wrong.

I saw this thread : [TensorFlow: training on my own image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340129/tensorflow-training-on-my-own-image)

And the doc of the official web site

code:

```
import tensorflow as tf #tensor flow
import numpy as np
import glob, os


from pprint import pprint


filenames = list()

os.chdir(".")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    filenames.append( file)





# filenames = ['im_01.jpg', 'im_02.jpg', 'im_03.jpg', 'im_04.jpg']


filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)


reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, content = reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(filename, channels=3)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224, 224])


image_batch = tf.train.batch([resized_image], batch_size=10000)

print (image_batch)
```

if I change the batch size, it change nothing to the output.
I really dont know why it doesnt works

print return

```
 Tensor("batch:0", shape=(10000, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
```

How can I do ?
thanks
thomas

Comment: 10000?? Try something like 64 or 128

Comment: yep I have already tried a number arround 100, it is the same thing. "10000" my last test.

Comment: Whats the size of your dataset?

Comment: Add `labels=[1,0,1,0]` and than `image_batch, label_batch=tf.train.batch([resized_image, labels], batch_size=2)`

Comment: I have about 10000 images of cat and 10000 images of dogs. I have the same output with your solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: Note that batch size is the number of training samples you train per training step, and it is not the dataset size. You might want to read on mini-batch gradient descent, for example here: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/9zJUs/mini-batch-gradient-descent