# Python Tensorflow:UnimplementedError: Cast string to int32 is not supported

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

everyone.
I am new to Tensorflow
When I wrote the code like this in this part :

```
def get_batch(image,label,new_height,new_width,batch_size,capacity):
image=tf.cast(image,tf.string)
label=tf.cast(image,tf.int32)

input_queue= tf.train.slice_input_producer([image,label])
label=input_queue[1]
image_contents=tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
image=tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_contents,channels=3)

image=tf.image.resize_images(image,(new_height,new_width))
image=tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
image_batch,label_batch=tf.train.batch([image,label],batch_size=batch_size,capacity=capacity,num_threads=8)

label_batch=tf.reshape(label_batch,[batch_size])
return image_batch,label_batch
```

Btw. the Args: images ,labels are returned from another function, which read the files that store images and labels.And I define the new_height and new_width as constant when I run this code

```
 I met the error like this:

UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): Cast string to int32 is not supported
         [[Node: Cast_1 = Cast[DstT=DT_INT32, SrcT=DT_STRING, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Cast/x)]]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-5c65685872d1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/yanghang/ugthesis/mean subtraction.py', wdir='C:/Users/yanghang/ugthesis')

  File "C:\Users\yanghang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\yanghang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/yanghang/ugthesis/mean subtraction.py", line 102, in <module>
    coord.join(threads)

  File "C:\Users\yanghang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)

  File "C:\Users\yanghang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value

  File "C:\Users\yanghang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\queue_runner_impl.py", line 234, in _run
    sess.run(enqueue_op)

  File "C:\Users\yanghang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "C:\Users\yanghang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)

  File "C:\Users\yanghang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)

  File "C:\Users\yanghang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)`
```

Could u tell me how to solve this problem?
   Thanks in advance

Comment: this error depends on the content of your image object, so please debug the image object and provide the result so we can help you.

Comment: Cast string to int32 is not supported ? I guess, because string is like"C:\\Users\\yanghang\\ugthesis\\data\\b\\normal.1.jpg'" so it can not be converted to int32,right?

Comment: You should use the `tf.data` library instead of the old queues: here is a [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets). Also, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340129) to import data from images.

Comment: Hi, Olivier, I try it 
`dataset=tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
def _parse_function(record):
    features={"image":tf.FixedLenFeature((),tf.string,default_value='')
              "label":tf.FixedLenFeature((),tf.int32,default_value='')}
# use tf.parse_single_example() function to extract the data            
    parsed=tf.parse_single_example(record,features)
    image_decoded=tf.image.decoded_image(parsed["image"]) 
    image_resize=tf.image.reshape(image_decoded,[200,200,1])
    label=tf.cast(parse["label"],tf.int32)
 return {"image":image,"label":label}`

Comment: Please edit your post with a clear question and what you already have as code.

Comment: Should the code be `label = tf.cast(label, tf.int32)`, rather than `label = tf.cast(image, tf.int32)`?

Comment: OMG, Tx, mrry!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @mrry, there was a typo in the code:

```py
label=tf.cast(image,tf.int32)
```

Which should instead be:

```py
label=tf.cast(label,tf.int32)
```