# How to create dataset of images from folder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset of 35,000+ images from [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection/data) in a folder. How can I turn these images into an array in python of `train_images` that I can feed into a tensor flow deep learning model?

Comment: Have you tried to use PIL library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1 (easy but not recommended)

Load your data with numpy, PIL or opencv and feed it to your network using placeholders. This implies that your data is small enough to fit in memory. Example code would look like

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data = []
for i in glob.glob('path/to/my/data/**/*.png', recursive=True):
    data.append(cv2.imread(i))

data = np.stack(data) # array of shape [num_images, height, width, channel]

def get_batch(data, batch_size):
    data_size = data.shape[0]
    indexes = list(range(data_size))
    np.random.shuffle(indexes)
    for i in range(0, data_size, batch_size):
        yield data[indexes[i:i+batch_size]]

images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, height, width, channel])
my_net = build_network(images)

...

for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    for batch_images in get_batch(data, batch_size):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={images: batch_images})
```

### Method 2 (more involved but scales better)

You should create TF Records from your data and use the queuing mechanism and dataset API from TensorFlow instead of placeholder.

Comment: Hi, I tried method 1 but I think the problem lies in the fact that I have it on an external drive, as I used this: `data_path = '/Volumes/G-DRIVE\ mobile\ USB-C/train '` and got a `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Volumes/G-DRIVE\\ mobile\\ USB-C/train '`  how do I get around this? Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the escaping character `\\`.

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify? I am new to this so it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Usually, when you have spaces in a path, like `my data` you need to escape the spaces with \. Try removing those extra \ and use `data_path='/Volumes/G-DRIVE mobile USB-C/train`.

Comment: Works! data_path='/Volumes/G-DRIVE mobile USB-C/train

Answer (score 0):

To get all the file/image name from your data set folder follow this

```
import os

# train_images list of name of files or images in data set folder 
train_images = list()

image_path = ' path to the data set (image) folder '
for image in os.walk(image_path):
    train_images.append(image[2]) 
# os.walk('path') traverse recursively so used index 2 to give file name in same folder only
```

> `trian_images` is required array which you can pass/feed to tensorflow.

follow this solution  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340129/tensorflow-training-on-my-own-image) by @Olivier Moindrot and pass train_images to filenames and label your data accordingly your needs .

Comment: No need to use the comments space to add info to *your own* answer - edit & update your answer instead!

Comment: @desertnaut thanks for improvising.