# How to include rgb and grayscale images in CNN using tf.data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use rgb images as input and grayscale images as label image based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340129/tensorflow-training-on-my-own-image). How can I modify the following code to define that the label images contain one channel?

```
# step 1
filenames = tf.constant(input_list)
labels = tf.constant(label_list)

# step 2: create a dataset returning slices of `filenames`
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))

# step 3: parse every image in the dataset using `map`
def _parse_function(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32)
    return image, label

dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
dataset = dataset.batch(2)

# step 4: create iterator and final input tensor
iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)
images, labels = iterator.get_next()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function to load an image with a varying number of channels:

```
def _parse_function(filename, channels):
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=channels)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    return image
```

Then:

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y:
    (
        _parse_function(x, channels=3),
        _parse_function(y, channels=1)
    )
)
```

Comment: @ Nicolas Gervais the input and target images are different. input images contain 3 bands and target images contain 1 band. label_list represents the list of target images. I am not sure how this can be included in the code.